# Update multiple columns based on different conditions for each column in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to join two tables **Tbl_LIN**and **CDETOPDE**. These tables has a common key **Element ID**. In the process of joining we also need to update two columns from **Tbl_LIN**; **Glossary_ID** and **DRD_ID**. It should be noted that these columns also belong to **CDETOPDE**. Our goal is to set **Tbl_LIN.Glossary_ID** as null if **CDETOPDE.Glossary_ID** is null. Similarly for the other columns **DRD_ID**. Here is attempt in Ms Access.

```
UPDATE tblLineage

INNER JOIN 

CDEtoPDE

ON tblLineage.Element_ID = CDEtoPDE.Element_ID

SET tblLineage.Glossary_ID = NULL

WHERE (CDEtoPDE.Glossary_ID  IS  NULL AND tblLineage.Glossary_ID IS NOT NULL)

UNION (

SET tblLineage.DRD_ID = NULL

WHERE 
(CDEtoPDE.DRD_ID  IS  NULL AND tblLineage.DRD_ID IS NOT NULL))
```

Multiple SET statements are not allowed in a single query therefore we thought of use a UNION but we got syntax error. Help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `UNION` and `WHERE` clauses you can put the `Iif` expression inside the `SET` clause:

```
UPDATE tblLineage
INNER JOIN 
CDEtoPDE
ON tblLineage.Element_ID = CDEtoPDE.Element_ID
SET tblLineage.Glossary_ID = iif(CDEtoPDE.Glossary_ID  IS  NULL AND tblLineage.Glossary_ID IS NOT NULL, NULL, tblLineage.Glossary_ID),
    tblLineage.DRD_ID = Iif(CDEtoPDE.DRD_ID  IS  NULL AND tblLineage.DRD_ID IS NOT NULL, NULL, tblLineage.DRD_ID)
```